# The hash value of the URL in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

The router mode is "history", and I want to  valid each request in the middleware which will redirect the request to a given page when the request is invalid. In my case, the request that does not exist in the white_path will be redirect to '/500':

```
export default function (context) {
    const white_path = new Array('/login', '/404', '/500')
    const cur_path = context.route.path
    if(white_path.indexOf(cur_path) < 0){
        context.redirect(301, '/500')
    }
}
```

But the problem is that when I input the url: ***http://localhost:3000/blog/SampleTitle/#first-paragraph***, but then it redirects to ***http://localhost:3000/500#first-paragraph***. **Why the hash value does not disappear?** In the middleware, the hash value is empty, but after redirect to the client,  the hash value becomes the one appear in the last url.

How can I solve it? Thank your very much!

Comment: Have you try `push` instead of `redirect`?

Comment: @AdamOrlov No, but context does not has function push. My solution is not perfect: I clear the **window.location.hash** at the **beforeMounted**. But there will be a delay when the url changes.